# Eclipse: Complete Build State Clean/Reset

Tags: eclipse, rebuild

Is there a good way to reset Eclipse build state *completely*?

I am stuck getting 'Building all...' on each build (manual, BTW), even though it seems to finish normally, and it has been working just fine for weeks, and I've had this issue before, but it would resolve itself on one or more rebuilds; all of which leads me to believe that there is something internal that gets stuck in a wrong state.

---

Clean Project does not seem to do it. And the full rebuild 'says' it does a clean anyway, 'cleaning output folder'.

Clean + Close Project + Restart Eclipse does not seem to do it either (which fact I find rather unsatisfying and weird).

---

I suppose a re-import could do it.

Perhaps re-import under a different name?

But maybe there's something easier than re-import. Perhaps deleting some file or folder in Eclipse persisted state?

---

(Maybe tag this 'internals'? I am asking for specific solutions, but I am certainly interested in the IDE internals too, whether that will help solve this issue or not.)

Comment: Hm, maybe changing the project name could have some effect? At least if the build state is cached based on project name.

Comment: Which project builder are you talking about? Java? Maven? If you use Maven, there might be cycles which can be found with the _Maven Workspace Build_ view. Otherwise, you might try to start Eclipse with the `-clean` option. It might also caused by a plugin you have installed. Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder; that's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow that can cause serious problems (just in case somebody will tell you to do that).

Comment: @howlger It's the java builder only. I turned off the maven builder/s because they were slow. And it's only a straight-up java project anyway. Thanks for the .metaspace warning :). So there's a -clean startup option that does something more than the 'clean' menu option, interesting, I shall promptly google that...

Comment: Added "-clean" to "eclipse.ini". Restarted. Verified in "About Eclipse > Installation Details > Configuration". Did not help, unfortunately. I'll try re-importing next...

Comment: These a different things. _Project > Clean..._ means to do a full build from scratch instead of building incrementally. `-clean` means not to use caches on start-up. Both depends on the plugins used. You can also have build cycles without Maven. Close all projects and open only the ones needed to find out if it caused by a project. It might also caused by a plugin installed (I had this once, even without using the installed plugin).

Comment: I see. I have only one project open. I don't think it's about build cycles. I strongly suspect some internal bug, some race condition, involving build state, and in how Eclipse decides it's time to rebuild everything. I've had this issue, intermittently, for years, over many Eclipse versions (on that note, thanks for your Eclipse releases info channel on YT). But who knows.

Comment: Thanks. What do you have in _Project > Properties: Builders_? Only the _Java Builder_? You might try a fresh workspace and import the project without copy the settings. You might also try a fresh Eclipse installation without additional installed plugins.

Comment: I'm trying the re-import idea as we speak. Only the Java Builder is active.

Comment: Well, I think I got it working now, and it seems to have had something to do with two nested classes of the same name modulo case. Showed up as 'A resource exists with a different case' doing "tail -f .metadata/.log". But who knows.

Comment: On Windows? In your source code?

Comment: Yes, two types declared in the same Java 'nesting scope'. Mac/Catalina, APFS. I know Mac file systems are traditionally case-insensitive, which may be bad in just this kind of situation. I thought they'd outgrown that since HFS+ at least, and certainly APFS.